# rails updating by conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web

Im trying to update the cells in the column deleted to true in Feedback table where fid and pid are equals to the given params

```
Feedback.update_all ({:deleted => true} , {:fid => params[:fid] , :pid => params[:pid]})
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Feedback.where(fid: params[:fid], pid: params[:pid).update_all(deleted: true)
```

Done!